# Get Date and Time from selected Photo imagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

When the user selects an image from there photos how can I get the date and time from that selected image. Please and thanks in advance!

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

        //dismiss imagepicker controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

NSDictionary *metadataDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
    // do something with the metadata

NSLog(@"meta : %@ \n\n",metadataDictionary);
```

}

Comment: You saved my day :D

Comment: let metadataDictionary = info.values
                        //value
                        // do something with the metadata
                        print("******************************************************")
                        print("meta : \(metadataDictionary)")
                        print("******************************************************")